# How to get overall F-statistics form a model with random effects

Tags: mixed-models, random-effects

I've been using the lmer function in lme4 and it gives me the coefficients for the independent variables so that I could build the predictive model, but it doesn't give me the F statistics for each factor. I tried to find how to get those (F stats) online and it said the anova function in nlme gives you F statistics... and this does give me them, but it only gives me the numerator degrees of freedom so I cant verify (and also doubt since its an ANOVA) that it is taking into account the random factor that I have in my mixed model, so they are probably not the correct F-statistics.

How can I get F-statistics for a model that accounts for random effects? I'm able to run the tukey pairwise using lsmeans to check specific comparisons, but I want to justify running those with the F-statistics first.

Answer (score 1):

The `car::Anova` function is probably the better choice. Both it and `anova` do indeed compute anova tables, in the broad sense of testing contributions of factors to the model, but `anova` tests their sequential contributions rather than their marginal ones. Don’t worry much about the denominator df; they’ll be similar to the df for the same family of comparisons from `lsmeans`. You might consider switching to the **emmeans** package though, as **lsmeans** will not be developed further.